# Gait detection using acclerometer

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to detect whether a person is climbing or descending stairs using the data obtained from an accelerometer alone?

## EDIT

If you have a accelerometer in your pocket(Mobile phone) then what about the forward acceleration along the z- axis. Won't that help to distinguish walking and climbing as forward acceleration in both cases will be different.

Comment: A given person or any person? Normal stair climbing/descending or taking into account pathological cases? The magnitudes of accelerations are similar **typically** (probably more variation between people and different rates), but the shape is different.

Comment: Any person , normal stair climbing/descending , not taking any pathological cases into account

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this Powerpoint presentation](http://www.xsens.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Biomechanics-Biomechanics-of-Stair-Climbing.pdf) from Carlos Galván-Duque Gastélum
Ruth Mayagoitia-Hill and Fady Wakil at King's College London:

Ascending:

[image]

Descending:

[image]

It should be possible to process the vertical acceleration signal to distinguish between the two cases- there's a clear difference.

Comment: I agree that presentation does show graphs which indicate ascending and descending gait might be distinguished. However, AFAICT, they didn't try. So how might that part of the problem be tackled? That seems to be 'the nub' of the question.

Comment: @gbulmer I would think that identifying the major bumps and calculating the correlation between the (time and amplitude) scaled signal and two model signals would have a good chance of success, but then I don't consider myself a signal processing guru.

Comment: I'm not a signal processing guru. I thought you might have a useful reference, but no worries if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. I hate "just google" answers, but this is a huge field with tons of papers.  A fair review is Sejdic, et al, A Comprehensive Assessment of Gait Accelerometry Signals in Time, Frequency and Time-Frequency Domains IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON NEURAL SYSTEMS AND REHABILITATION ENGINEERING, VOL. 22, NO. 3, MAY 2014

Your search term should be "gait accelerometry", and you should probably pay attention to google scholar.

Another useful paper that specifically discusses stairs is http://www.academia.edu/5472187/Accelerometry_based_classification_of_gait_patterns_using_empirical_mode_decomposition  -- though there are probably dozens of approaches, and I hesitate to recommend any one over any other.

Comment: That specific reference is 'paywalled', so it isn't very useful unless I fork out the money. Can you reference one which is available to the masses (i.e. stingy people like me)?

Comment: @gbulmer Sometimes if you approach the authors with a good story about what you're doing they'll send you a copy of their paper. Technically it's probably against the rules- the journals usually retain all copyright, but it happens.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - "Sometimes if you approach the authors ... they'll send you a copy of their paper" is useful individually, but seems less useful in the context of a ee.se answer. Specifically, if Scott Seidman's answer had a non-paywalled paper, *anyone* interested in the question and answers, could have a look at a paper with minimal hassle.

Comment: @gbulmer You're right, I should not have @'d you on that comment!

Comment: @gbulmer - yes- which is why I didn't provide a link.  Much of the work in this area is in the scientific literature, which will generally be heavily paywalled.  If you need it, you need it, and the least expensive way to get it is interlibrary loans, which will probably run about $5US